# how to show Can’t automatically merge in github

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull, git-merge-conflict

When I push my code in Github and want to merge code with the main branch but shows "Can’t automatically merge. Don’t worry, you can still create the pull request."

I am tried many times in many ways but failed. Please give me any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a case of "failed". Your branch has a merge conflict with the main branch. A merge conflict is not an error, an issue, or a failure. It's just a thing. You will need to resolve the conflict eventually. But there is no rush.

One approach is to merge the main branch into your branch and resolve the conflict (on your computer).

Another way is to wait until your PR is approved and resolve the conflict as you merge it into the main branch (which you can do using GitHub's interface).